# CodePipeline Beanstalk Deploy Version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have a straitforward CodePipeline setup shown here:
[image: pipeline]

There is almost zero configurations required with this pipeline. Artifact names, project names, that's it (and that's great). I get this error every time I deploy via `git push`, but the code that I deploy will still be deployed and works. This error appears in the "Health" tab in Beanstalk.

full error:

```
 Incorrect application version "code-pipeline-1527260772846-80f1d98eca5f35bcc778b85efec9c71499bafeac" (deployment 20). Expected version "code-pipeline-1527254940377-f7fbab90f239cbdc2f54518cd8408082432e8e79" (deployment 1).
```

readble version:

```
 Incorrect application version "code-pipeline-some-id" (deployment 20). 
 Expected version "code-pipeline-some-other-id" (deployment 1).
```

I can see all the changes in my app. Beanstalk says the status of my instance is "degraded". If I deploy the same app from cli with `eb deploy` it works without warnings/errors, everything looks healthy. My whole AWS infrastructure is managed via Terraform. How can i modify this "application version" and make Beanstalk happy?

Comment: Familiarise yourself with and if it doesn't meet your requirements, disable enhanced monitoring.

Comment: @GeorgeRushby Thank you, i did that, my guess now is that i didn't setup role quite well and the pipeline service can not increment the beanstalk deployment ID.